# canonical form of a 16 entry square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Question:
Suppose A is a 4×4 matrix with a single real eigenvalue and two linearly independent eigenvectors. Describe the possible canonical forms for A and show that A may indeed be transformed into one of these canonical forms. Describe explicitly the conditions under which A is transformed into a particular form.

There is a question like this here but the answer is not thorough. I'm curious to see how many canonical forms there are and how they are gotten. I jusst learned about block matrices. An example would be nice if possible